# Migrate embedded object to separate table. Room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

`CertificateElementEntity` entity had an embedded class `ImgData`.

I have divided `CertificateElementEntity`and `ImageData` into separate tables.

But now I can't figure out how to make the migration.

```
open class CertificateElementEntity(
@IgnoreJson
@PrimaryKey
@ColumnInfo(name = "local_id")
var localId: Long? = null,
var data: String? = null,
var imageData: ImgData? = null)
```

Maybe someone made similar migrations

Answer (score -1):

You can try this general migration schema (honestly, I haven't experienced such a migration, so may be there is way easier):

1. Create temporary table [CertificateElementEntityTemp] with the same structure.
2. Copy all data from table [CertificateElementEntity] to [CertificateElementEntityTemp].
3. Drop table [CertificateElementEntity].
4. Create table [ImgData].
5. Create table [CertificateElementEntity] with new structure (with just **imageId** instead all fields from embedded table). Create Foreign Key for [imageId].
6. Copy needed data from [CertificateElementEntityTemp] to [ImgData].
7. Copy needed data from [CertificateElementEntityTemp] to [CertificateElementEntity].
8. Drop table [CertificateElementEntityTemp].

All this of course you should write in migration section with equivalent SQL statements.

Comment: @kalugin1912 So, you've tried this or it's not what you've asked about?